# Android: Having my EditText fields borrow variables from other methods?

Tags: java, android

I have a little experience in Java and I'm only new to the Android environment. I have previously created an encryption algorithm in Java (using a simple shift cipher). I have since made changes in order for it to successfully fit into Android code, however I do not have it quite working yet. The plan is to get a user to enter plaintext into one EditText field, a key in the second and their Email in the third. Upon clicking the button 'Send', the cipher text will be sent to their Email. Below, I have included in comments the main method from the Java version (now in my onCreate method).

```
public class ScreenNext extends Activity {

int key = 0;
static char ch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_next);

    EditText emailT;//Import  EditTexts (Key and Email)  
    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);//Import button1 (Send)         final EditText passT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTogg);//passT variable for Password Text for EditText field
    final EditText keyT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etKey);
    final EditText passT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTogg);//passT variable for Password Text for EditText field

    //convert the JOption Panes now into Android equivalents
    //String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("(1) Encrypt \n"+ "(2) Close");
    //String subKey = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your ideal key");
    //String message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter message");
    //String cText = subcipher_1.message(choice, subKey, message);
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cText);//send cText as email

}//End onCreate

public static String message(String choice, String subKey, String message) {


    int Option = Integer.parseInt(choice);//Must pareseInt
    int key = Integer.parseInt(subKey);
    message = message.toLowerCase();

        //If the key is 26, prompt the user to change the key

        if (key % 26 == 0) {

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can't use a modulus of 26 as a key", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    ScreenNext subcipher_1 = null;
    String CipherTxt = subcipher_1.encrypt(message, key);
    return CipherTxt;
}

// Message prompt method finished, now we create the method that has the
// encrypting algorithms
public static String encrypt(String Txt, int key) {


    //local var cipherText of type string is init empty
    String CipherTxt = "";//May be able to remove this'un 
    String cText="";
    //enhanced for loop 
    // start at 0, go until "as long as input text" 
    for (int i = 0; i < Txt.length(); i++) {
        //get a char from the string at index i (start at 0 work through to end of string)
        // and store in local var extractedChar for type char
        char extractedChar = Txt.charAt(i);
        /* enhanced for loop 
         * start at 0, go until end of user entered cipherKeyValue
         * either set to lowercase a or add one to the char
         * uses the checkifz method
         */
        for (int j = 0; j < key; j++) {
            ScreenNext subcipher_1 = null;
            if (subcipher_1.checkIfZ(extractedChar) == true) {
                extractedChar = 'a';
            } else {
                extractedChar++;
            }
            CipherTxt= new StringBuilder().append(extractedChar).toString();
        }
        //add extracted char to builder object
        //change object builder to string and assing to cipherText of type String
        //create new object builder from StringBuilder class
        cText = cText.concat(CipherTxt);
    }
    //Pass the cipherText value out of the method to whom ever called it

    return cText;
}
// public method properCase, makes all strings lowercase
public String properCase(String input) {
    if (input.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    if (input.length() == 1) {
        return input.toLowerCase();//currently set to default; will shtill compile 
    }
    return input.substring(0).toLowerCase();//no locale set
}
//Check if the letter is Z so we can loop back to A
public static boolean checkIfZ(char cInput) {
    boolean yesNo = false;
    if (cInput++ == 0x7A) {
        yesNo = true;
    }
    return yesNo;
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.screen_next, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Naturally I understand that JOptionPane doesn't exist in Android, so I will be prompting the user to enter their inputs in EditText fields. I have three of these: passT for Plaintext Input, keyT for the Key input and emailT for the users Email.

How can I go about incorporating the EditText fields to their corresponding variables in the encryption and message methods?

And advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Click listener to the `Send` button and `onClick` event get the values from the fields.

```
send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String keyText = keyT.getText().toString();
    String passText = passT.getText().toString();
}
});
```

Comment: I appreciate this help, although it doesn't fully help me in this circumstance. I need to have my plain text and key input work its way into my encryption method, and have cText (my Cipher Text) become the output (I might toast that at first upon hitting 'Send' to check if it works).

Comment: I didn't get your question. You want pass the plaintext and the keytext as parameters to your encryption method and then retreive the result and set the value in the cipher EditText field, right?

Comment: Yes, I would like for the user entered plain text and key to be passed in as parameters into the encryption method. Then I want the result to be sent to the Email that is entered in the Email text field.

Comment: In my answer I have specified how to accept input from EditText. You can go ahead and pass these values as parameters to your encryption function. At which point are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Ok, so you're saying I should apply these values into my encryption method, and then add 'send to email address' function into my onClick? Thanks very much, hopefully I'll be able to sort that out.